# process is terminated due to StackOverflowException from bool function C++

Tags: c++, stack-overflow

I am trying to make a bool function that will allow an input of a string and the input of a substring to be searched in that string's input. The bool function should search recursively for a match, then return true if there is a match inside of the string. For example: 'word' is entered as the string, then 'or' is the substring I am looking for inside the string. The function should then return true since 'or' is inside 'word'. When I run the code, on the command line it will say, "process is terminated due to StackOverFlowException" I am confused as to what this error means and how it relates to my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

bool find(string s, string t)
{

if(s.length() <= 1){
    return false;
}
int t_len = t.length() - 1;
string se = s.substr(0, t_len);

if(se == t){
    return true;
}
else
s.erase(0,0);
return find(s, t);
}
int main()
{

string s;
string t;
cout << "Enter string s: " << endl;
cin >> s;
cout << "Enter string t: " << endl;
cin >> t;

bool is_found = find(s, t);
if(is_found = true)
{
    cout << "Found: " << t << " in " << s << endl;
}

system("pause");
return 0;

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call to erase is not deleting any characters. The definition of erase is:

```
erase( size_type index = 0, size_type count = npos );
```

So you want to erase `1` character, not `0` characters.

Additionally, your test at the end should read:

```
if(is_found == true)
```

as otherwise, you're trying to assign is_found the value true and test that value (which will always be true in that case.

Additionally, you have:

```
string se = s.substr(0, t_len);
```

where `t_len` is incorrect (off by one), so the string comparison will not work.

Fundamentally, it looks like you've not understood the definitions of [`erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase) or [`substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr), which would be essential to getting this to work properly.